# Form inside loop not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, forms, loops

In the last couple of days I just tried and tried to resolve this problem but I really don't know how to deal with it.

I have this inventory.php for a game that I'm trying to make.
The class Inventory works and methods inside it works too.
My problem is with the form loop beacause I don't know how to make it work properly. I want the buttons to work for every item but something is messed up and it works just for the second (one or last one).Doesn't matter what button I press the gold is taken for the second button.

I know the code is messy and I'm sure it could be made more easly but I'm trying to resolve this problem.

The code:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {

    /**
    * Inventory
    */
    class Inventory
    {
        public $dbh;
        public $id;
        public $id_item;
        public $equip;
        public $strength;
        public $endurance;
        public $intelligence;
        public $luck;
        public $dexterity;
        public $gold;    
        public $gold_sell;


        function __construct(PDO $dbh, $id, $id_item, $equip, $strength, $endurance, $intelligence, $luck, $dexterity, $gold, $gold_sell)
        {
            $this->dbh = $dbh;
            $this->id = $id;
            $this->id_item = $id_item;
            $this->equip = $equip;
            $this->strength = $strength;
            $this->endurance = $endurance;
            $this->intelligence = $intelligence;
            $this->luck = $luck;
            $this->dexterity = $dexterity;
            $this->gold = $gold;
            $this->gold_sell = $gold_sell;
        }

        function PrintDetails(){
            print "Id:".($this->id)."<br>";
            print "Id Item:".($this->id_item)."<br>";
            print "Equip:".($this->equip)."<br>";
            print "Strength:".($this->strength)."<br>";
            print "Endurance:".($this->endurance)."<br>";
            print "Intelligence:".($this->intelligence)."<br>";
            print "Luck:".($this->luck)."<br>";
            print "Dexterity:".($this->dexterity)."<br>";
            print "User gold:".($this->gold)."<br>";       
            print "Sale price:".($this->gold_sell)."<br>";
        }

        function SellItem(PDO $dbh, $id_item, $gold, $gold_sell){

            $this->gold = $this->gold + $this->gold_sell;

            print "GOLD :".($this->gold)."<br>";
                $sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE attributes SET gold = :gold WHERE id = :id");
                $sth->bindParam(":gold", $this->gold);
                $sth->bindParam(":id", $_SESSION['id']);
                $sth->execute();


                        print "iditr :".($this->id_item)."<br>";
            // $inventory->SellItem($dbh, $row2['id_item'],$row3['gold'],$row4['gold_sell']); }


        }
    }

    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, username FROM user WHERE id = ".$_SESSION['id']."");
    $sth->execute();
    $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $sth3 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM attributes WHERE id = ".$_SESSION['id']."");
    $sth3->execute();
    $row3 = $sth3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



    $sth2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id = ".$_SESSION['id']."");
    $sth2->execute();

    while ($row2 = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $sth4 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = ".$row2['id_item']."");
    $sth4->execute();



    $row4 = $sth4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print $row2['id'];
    print $row2['username'];
    print $row2['name']."<br>";
    $inventory = new Inventory($dbh,$row['id'],$row2['id_item'],$row2['equip'],$row4['strength'],$row4['endurance'],$row4['intelligence'],$row4['luck'],$row4['dexterity'],$row3['gold'],$row4['gold_sell']);
    $inventory->PrintDetails();
 $inventory->SellItem($dbh,$row2['id_item'],$row3['gold'],$row4['gold_sell']);

?>
<form id='<?php echo $row2["id_item"]; ?>' name="submit"  action="" method="POST">
    <button type='submit' value='<?php echo $row2['id_item']; ?>'>Add</button>
</form>


<?php

}

}
```

If I view my source this comes up:

```
<div id="main">

2motocDagger
    <br></br>
      Id:2
    <br></br>
      Id Item:1
    <br></br>
      Equip:0
    <br></br>
      Strength:10
    <br></br>
      Endurance:6
    <br></br>
      Intelligence:0
    <br></br>
      Luck:0
    <br></br>
      Dexterity:3
    <br></br>
      User gold:202
    <br></br>
      Sale price:5
    <br></br>
      GOLD :207
    <br></br>
      iditr :1
    <br></br><form id="1" method="POST" action="" name="submit"><button value="1" type="submit">
      Add
    </button></form>



2motocStaff
    <br></br>
      Id:2
    <br></br>
      Id Item:2
    <br></br>
      Equip:0
    <br></br>
      Strength:4
    <br></br>
      Endurance:5
    <br></br>
      Intelligence:12
    <br></br>
      Luck:0
    <br></br>
      Dexterity:4
    <br></br>
      User gold:202
    <br></br>
      Sale price:4
    <br></br>
      GOLD :206
    <br></br>
      iditr :2
    <br></br><form id="2" method="POST" action="" name="submit"><button value="2" type="submit">
      Add
    </button></form></div>
```

The form id's are different so that is not the problem.
If I click the first button the gold inside my database is updated with 4 gold and I want to make every button to work properlt.5 gold I want to be updated (Dagger's gold). How can I do that?

I'm sorry that I made such a big post.
Thank you

Comment: is there a reason why you use `<button` instead of `<input type='submit'...` ? Do you try to submit the form via javascript?

Comment: I have to say it it's bugging me to look at, by defining a class definition inside your `$_SESSION` if check you've essentially ruined the object's reusability.

Comment: You seem to be using $_SESSION['id'] in a number of places. But I can't see anywhere where you're setting it - is it getting the ID of the item that's being sold somewhere?

Comment: SESSION Id is set on a different file and works properly for sure. It is getting the id of the user.

Answer (score 0):

please try it like this:

```
<form id='f1' method="POST" action="[setup an url here]" >
<input type="hidden" name="refid" value="1" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

and then ask for submitting like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $refid = intval($_POST['refid']);
    // do what you want here..
}
```

Comment: This is an improvement but I think that I have to put the UPDATE inside of if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {} because when I click the Add button same thing happens.The question is how do I do that and make it  work properly? 
Thank you for the response steven. About buton instead of input, I don't know I just thought since I want a button I should make one. Has input some advantages?. I will probably use js.

Thank you again but the problem is still there but I feel that I moved on a little.

Comment: is it the SellItem Method which sould be called when click the button? or something different?

Comment: so put it inside the if-block. But you should not do that inside your loop but somewhere above. check for submit inside your loop makes no sense.

Comment: maybe you should improve your Inventory Class. All db-queries could be done by that class in different methods. So the methods can return the query data. And put the class in a seperate file so you can require it and PUT IT NOT INSIDE a `if(isset($_SESSION...`-block!

Comment: dont't give up and you will get it. Having a good structure is important for your overview.

Comment: I'm not giving up. I started PHP, MySQL and POO last week (Monday) and I think that I learned a lot in one week. I knew that will be some tricky moments. I will post here what I've worked in few hours because I can't do it right now. Thanks steven